# I am trying to write a procedure that takes two arguments 'pattern' and 'question' and checks if the occurrence of the wildcards

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to write a procedure that takes two arguments 'pattern' and 'question' and checks if the occurrence of the wildcards "..." and "_" in pattern matches the question.
For example:

```
(matching? '(a b ... e) '(a b c d f)) = #f (false)
(matching? '(a b ... e _ (x y)) '(a b 1 2 3 4 5 e card y)) = #t (true)
```

```
    > (define matching?   (lambda (pattern question)
    >         (let ((len1 (length pattern)) (len2 (length question)))
    >           (cond ((null? pattern) (null? question))
    >                 ((null? question) #f)
    >                 ((and (> len1 1) (eq? (car pattern) '...) (eq? len2
                                                                       0))
                                                                 #f)
    >                 ((or (and (> len1 1) (eq? (car pattern) '_)) (and 
                                                   (not (eq? len1 0)) (not 
    >                  (eq len2 0)) (= len1 len2))) (matching? (cdr pattern
                                                    (cdr question)))
    >                 ((and (> len1 0) (eq? (car pattern) '...)) (matching?
                       (cdr pattern) question))
    >     
    >                 
    >                 (else #f)))))
```

Comment: What is the problem? What are `'...` and `'_` supposed to match? (By the way, it is almost always a mistake to use `length`.)

Comment: those are the wildcards. (matching? '(a b ... e) '(a b c d f)) = #f ,                    (matching? '(a b ... e _ (x y)) '(a b 1 2 3 4 5 e card y)) = #t (true)

Comment: Yes, you gave those two vague examples already. Don't you have an actual definition of what the wildcards should match? (Also, you still haven't mentioned what your problem is.)

Comment: My guess is that your parentheses are messed up. (Note that your `(eq? lenX 0)` conditions are never true due to the first two conditions.)